# Stuck seatbelt on a 1998 Plymouth Breeze

Tags: seat-belt

I have a 1998 Plymouth Breeze that has a drivers seat belt that is stuck so that in does not roll out so that it can be used but it does not roll back in either, it's just stuck extended part way. Does anyone know of any way to loosen the belt or is it neccesary to replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the perfect solution, but after removing the panel covering the belt roll, I touched the roll with my finger and it unstuck, however when the weather gets better here I will take out the roll and see if the roll break (the part that stops the roll in case if hard breaking) is maybe not lubricated enough.